# How to add image in a button without using image button?

Tags: android, css, image, button

How to add image to button without using image button.
ill try on button but not get solution.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background to the button in your XML:

```
    android:background="@drawable/MY_IMAGE"
```

Or from code:

```
    myButton.setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.MY_IMAGE));
```